# Reshape array of structs on pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with the following schema:

```
|-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- comment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- html_body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- author_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uploads: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- attachments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- thumbnails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- mapped_content_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- width: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- height: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- inline: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- public: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
```

However, this has way more data than what I need. For each element of the `comment` array, I would like to concatenate first `comment.created_at` and then `comment.body` into a new struct column called `comment_final`.

The end goal is to build from that, a string column that flattens the entire array into a string html-like field.

For the end result, I would like to do the following:

`.withColumn('final_body',array_join(col('comment.body'),'<br/><br/>'))`.

Can someone help me out with the array/struct data modelling?

Comment: explode the array comment first.

Comment: Thanks! It was the right approach